# find function from graph

Tags: polynomials

I am asked to find an expression from the following graph [image]

I would say the graph only has zeroes at 5 so when ${f(x) = 0, x = - 5}$

or ${k(0 -5) = -5}$

=> ${-5k = -5}$

=> ${k = 1}$

So the factors are ${x - 5}$

The text book gives the answer ${{-1\over 5} + 2x - 5}$

I have absolutely no clue where this answer came from.

Comment: You know it is a downward opening parabola, (quadratic),  with only one root and you know its $y$ intercept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the parabola  has a double zero for $x=5$, its equation has the form $y=a(x-5)^2$ .

Now we can find $a$ substituting the coordinates of the given point $(0,-5)$ that gives
$$
-5=a\times 5^2 \Rightarrow a=-\frac{1}{5}
$$
and the equation is $t=-\frac{1}{5}(x-5)^2$